# Update jQuery Pagination without changing current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-pagination

I have a newsfeed where I am displaying data. I want every time when admin post something it appear on newsfeed.

Its easy with ajax with time interval but my problem is that I have jquery pagination so if I load new content it will replace old data and if user is on page 2 it will drag him to page one and user will be unable to navigate to all data.

Here is code.

```
$('#notess').click(function(){
        $('#dashb, #add_form, #s_add_form, #s_edit_form, #edit_form').hide();
        $.post( 'ajax/notes.php', '', function(data){
            $('.dc').html(data);
        });
    });
```

I have explain my idea and question in the attached pic.

[image]

Comment: Please show your js code where you get new data from your Ajax Call

Comment: @Matt.k I have added the code

Comment: instead of `$('.dc').html(data)` `use $('.dc').append(data)`

Comment: @Matt.k
Yes thats what I explained in the image. I want to append but only new data. if I used append data as you described it will duplicate data.

Comment: How does it get duplicated If you just append a new data every time ?

Comment: @Matt.k Thanks for your continues replies.  By sending request I receive all data new and old. but I want some check which separate both an tell me this is new data and I can put it on the top of the list.

Comment: Please show your data sample(Structure) and the Html you generate

Comment: function is shown in my question it is calling php file which is returning <li> I append it in <ul>